# Find the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} k_n/2^n$ for $k_1=0$ and $k_{n+1}=k_n+\sqrt{1+k_n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

$k_n$ is defined with $k_1=0$ and $k_{n+1}=k_n+\sqrt{1+k_n^2}$.
This is homework, please do not provide a complete solution

edit : One of the many things I tried is to make it the root of an equation like this . I first found that and then tried $k_{n+1}=\sqrt{1+2 k_n k_{n+1}}$ then $(\lim_{n\to \infty} k_{n+1}/2^{n+1})^2=\lim_{n\to \infty}  (1+2 k_n k_{n+1})/2^{2n+2}=\lim_{n\to \infty}  k_n k_{n+1}/2^{2n+1}$ but then I was stuck and found nothing to continue. All my other trials ended up stuck.

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: Why the thumbs down?
Robin: I tried a lot of stuff but none gave me any progress. I tried many ways to calculate $k_{n+1}/2^{n+1}$ from $k_n/2^n$ but none were useful for me.
I don't understand the thumbs downs. I did something wrong?

Comment: The downvotes are because you didn't demonstrate any effort in asking your question. For instance, you haven't told us what you've already tried.

Comment: Robin: I'm sorry, I didn't know it was needed because nothing interesting came out of it. I really have no idea how to approach this problem, and all the things I tried doing ended up completely useless.

Comment: You could, at least, write down what you have tried.

Comment: Robin: okay, here

Comment: Some may be downvoting because of the sentence "This is homework, please be complete in your explanation", which many would interpret as "Do my homework for me".  I think you would get a much better response by changing it to "This is homework, please do not provide a complete solution".

Comment: Antonio: Oh, really really sorry. I realise it sounds cocky now. I will change it.

Comment: Now the question is surely deserving of an upvote :)

Comment: Much better now

Comment: Here are two comments to get you started: First, the limit, which you can compute numerically, is $1/\pi$. Second, the limit depends on the initial value $k_1 = 0$.

Comment: Should I just accept the answer now or wait for more answers? I saw someone saying to always wait in another question and I don't want to mess up again by accepting too fast.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333944/how-to-evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-fraca-n2n-1-if-a-0-0-and-a-n and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175041/convergence-of-sequence-given-by-x-1-1-and-x-n1-x-n-sqrtx-n21

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to think just a little bit outside the box for this one and not bruteforce your way through to a solution. The first thing that jumped at me was the $\sqrt{1+k^2}$, which made me think that either the hyperbolic sine and cosine are going to be useful here, or it's the tangent and secant. The latter was the right approach.

---

First, two elementary lemmas we'll use:

> Lemma 1: $\displaystyle \tan{x}+\sec{x}=\tan{\left( \frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}$
>
> Lemma 2: $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n 2^{-i}=1-2^{-n}$

---

Now, we have:

- $k_0=\tan{0}=0$
- $k_1=\tan{0}+\sqrt{1+\tan{0}^2}=\tan{0}+|\sec{0}|=\tan{0}+\sec{0}= \tan{(0/2+\pi/4)}$
- $k_2=\tan{\pi/4}+\sec{\pi/4}=\tan{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4} \right)\right)}$
- ...
- $k_n=\tan{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4} \cdots \frac{1}{2^n} \right)\right)}=\tan{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\left(1-2^{-n} \right)\right)}$

The general form above is only true because for $0 \leq x < \pi/2$, we have $|\sec{x}|=\sec{x}$.

---

So now, we calculate our limit:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{k_n}{2^n} &=& \lim_{n\to \infty} 2^{-n} \tan{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\left(1-2^{-n} \right)\right)} \\ &=& \lim_{x\to 0} x \tan{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\left(1-x \right)\right)}\\
&=& \left(  \lim_{x\to 0} \sin{\frac{\pi}{2}(1-x)} \right) \cdot \left( \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\cos{\frac{\pi}{2}(1-x)}} \right)\\
&=& 1 \cdot  \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}x}{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}\cos{\frac{\pi}{2}(1-x)}} \\
&=& \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} \sin{\frac{\pi}{2}(1-x)}}\\
&=& \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} \sin{\frac{\pi}{2}(1-0)}}\\&=& \boxed{\frac{2}{\pi}}
\end{eqnarray*}

And of course, the fourth equality is justified by l'Hôpital's rule.

---

So finally, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{k_n}{2^n}=\frac{2}{\pi}$ .

Comment: This answer made me happy.

Comment: Thank you sir. I still have to prove the lemma and go on this step by step, but the result 2/pi agrees with my computations, so I don't doubt the answer.

Comment: @ChantryCargill Thank you :)

@ user178056 If anything is unclear, you can ask me in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

suppose $k_n$ is $cotø$ then $$k_{n+1}=cotø+cosecø$=$(1+cosø)/sinø=2cos^(ø/2)/2sin(ø/2)cos(ø/2)=cot(ø/2)$$
now as $k_0=0$ take $k_0=cotπ/2$ therefore $k_n=cot(π/2^{n+1})$ now i guess you can solve the limit.the denominator will have $0*∞$ form where $2^n$ cancels.