# Convergence of sequence given by $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=x_n+\sqrt{x_n^2+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

Be $(x_n)_n\ge 1 $  such that $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=x_n+\sqrt{x_n^2+1}$ for every $n\ge 1$. Prove that the sequence $y_n=(2^n/x_n)_n \ge 1$ is convergent and find it s limit.

Being positive and decreasing, $y_n$ is clearly convergent. But finding it's limit really put me intro trouble. Any help?
 Thank you!

Comment: Hint1: use a trigonometric formula.

Comment: Strangely the desired limit always cancels out while I compute it.. that makes me sick...

Comment: I ran 100 itereations in MatLab and it would seem that $y_n \to {\pi \over 2}$, so as @GEdgar said some trigonometric formula might probably be useful, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Hint2: $\tan(\theta/2)$

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333944/how-to-evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-fraca-n2n-1-if-a-0-0-and-a-n and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942257/find-the-limit-lim-n-to-infty-k-n-2n-for-k-1-0-and-k-n1-k-n-sqrt1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {a_n}{2^{n-1}}=\frac 4{\pi}$ for $a_{n+1}=a_n+\sqrt{1+a_n^2}$ and $a_0=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465556/limit-lim-n-to-infty-frac-a-n2n-1-frac-4-pi-for-a-n1-a-n)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint3:**

$$
\tan\frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta+1}
$$
so
$$
\cot\frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{\cos\theta+1}{\sin\theta} = \cot\theta+\csc\theta
\\
=\cot\theta+\sqrt{\cot^2\theta+1}
$$
for $0<\theta<\pi$, so that $\csc\theta>0$.

**solution**
Prove by induction
$$
x_n = \cot\left(2^{-n}\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
$$
so that
$$
y_n = 2^n \tan\left(2^{-n}\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
$$
which converges to $\pi/2$.

**reference**
*Mathematics Magazine*, Problem 1214:
solution published vol. 59, no. 2, April, 1986, p. 117

**remark**
This calculation can be viewed as:
The perimeter of a regular $2^n$-gon circumscribed about a circle converges to the circumference of the circle.