# Find limit n tends to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$a_{n+1} = a_{n} +\sqrt{1+a^2_{n}}  , a_{1} = 0,
 \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{ 2^{n-1}}$
I tried it by using recurrence relation but couldn't proceed further. Also I tried to summation to cancel out .

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. Consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Ok sorry it won't happen again . Also I will edit this one

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Can I use mathjax in an android device

Comment: MathJax is just a TeX based markup language for typesetting Mathematics. See the links that I provided in my previous comment. As an example, $a_{n+1}$ may be typeset using `$a_{n+1}$`. Consider reviewing the edit that I proposed.

Comment: I am very sorry @st.math.  I am using it for first time . I didn't even know when I rejected it . I may have done it by mistake. Can I guide me please

Comment: Can you* guide me please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {a_n}{2^{n-1}}=\frac 4{\pi}$ for $a_{n+1}=a_n+\sqrt{1+a_n^2}$ and $a_0=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465556/limit-lim-n-to-infty-frac-a-n2n-1-frac-4-pi-for-a-n1-a-n)

Comment: Here is a website to help you write latex: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is recognizing the recurrence formula
$$
a_{n+1} = a_n + \sqrt{1+a_n^2}
$$
as a disguise for the half-angle formula for cotangent:
$$
\cot\frac{x}{2} = \cot x + \csc x = \cot x + \sqrt{1 + \cot^2 x}.
$$

Here, $a_1 = 0 = \cot \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, so $a_2 = 1 = \cot \dfrac{\pi}{4}$, and in general $a_n = \cot \dfrac{\pi}{2^n}$.

Using the fact that $\lim_{x\to 0} x\cot x = 1$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{2^{n-1}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\frac{2^n}{\pi}\bigg(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\cot \frac{\pi}{2^n}\bigg) = \frac{2}{\pi}.
$$

Comment: Thanks I tried it by substituting it with tanx but then it became tan(π/4 - x) then I left it there only.