# Is the limit of this sequence indeed 2 over Pi?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, pi

Sequences $(a_n), (b_n)$ are defined as follows:
\begin{align*}
a_0 = 0;\quad a_{n+1} = a_n + \sqrt{a_n^2+1}; 
\quad b_n = \frac{a_n}{2^n}; \quad n \geq 0.
\end{align*}
It is not difficult to prove that sequence $(b_n)$ has a limit when $n\to\infty$. Numerical simulation shows that this limit might be $\frac{2}{\pi}$. But I can't prove this.

I would like to get any insight which will help to settle this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {a_n}{2^{n-1}}=\frac 4{\pi}$ for $a_{n+1}=a_n+\sqrt{1+a_n^2}$ and $a_0=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465556/limit-lim-n-to-infty-frac-a-n2n-1-frac-4-pi-for-a-n1-a-n) – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a_%7Bn%2B1%7D%20%3D%20a_n%20%2B%20%5Csqrt%7Ba_n%5E2%2B1%7D%24)

Comment: Thanks, Martin! Definitely, this answers my question.