# Could someone point me in the right direction for this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and the series

$x_1=1;$

$n \in \mathbb{N^*};$
$x_{n+1} = x_n + \sqrt{x_n^2 + 1};$

Calculate: $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{2^n}{x_n})$

Please do not post a proof to this because I only want a hint.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1175041/42969 and some more, which can be bound with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x_%7Bn%2B1%7D%20%3D%20x_n%20%2B%20%5Csqrt%7Bx_n%5E2%20%2B%201%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: I just want a hint not a proof.

Comment: The first equations in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1465632/42969  and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1178287/42969 *are* hints.