# How to evaluate $\lim_{ n\to \infty }\frac{a_n}{2^{n-1}}$, if $a_0=0$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n+\sqrt{a_n^2+1}$?

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations

Let $a_1,a_2,..,a_n$ be sequence of real numbers such that $a_{n+1}=a_{n}+\sqrt{1+a_n^2}$ and $a_0=0$.

How to evaluate $\lim_{ n\to \infty  }\frac{a_n}{2^{n-1}}$ ?

Comment: I would rewrite the recurrence in terms of $b_n:=a_n/2^{n-1}$, and see where that leads... I'm afraid it only gives the qualitative conclusions in Yuval's answer.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: didn't you recognize the bisection formula for the cotangent?

Comment: Afraid I didn't, @Jack. For some reason I was trying to fit a hyperbolic cosine in there :-( Well done!

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175041/convergence-of-sequence-given-by-x-1-1-and-x-n1-x-n-sqrtx-n21 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942257/find-the-limit-lim-n-to-infty-k-n-2n-for-k-1-0-and-k-n1-k-n-sqrt1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since:
$$ \cot\frac{x}{2}=\cot x+\sqrt{1+\cot^2 x} $$
and $a_0=\cot\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have, by induction:
$$ a_n = \cot\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}} $$
and the wanted limit equals $\displaystyle{\color{red}{\frac{4}{\pi}}}$.

Comment: How did you get that cot stuff?What was your initial approach?

Comment: I just recognized the bisection formula for the cotangent. Trigonometry is useful, when doing math.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Just how often does one use the bisection formula of the cotangent ? XD

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM: [sometimes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0753) :D

Answer (score 3):

Write
$$ a_{n+1} = 2a_n + [\sqrt{1+a_n^2} - a_n], $$
and note that $\sqrt{1+a_n^2} - a_n \approx \frac{1}{2a_n}$. So roughly speaking, $a_{n+1} \approx 2a_n$, so that $a_n/2^{n-1}$ does approach a limit; this needs to be argued more formally, but I leave you the details. There is no particular reason that the limit have any nice expression; calculation shows that it is about 1.27323954473516.

Comment: ... better known as $\frac{4}{\pi}$, as shown below.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio it's relative on bass of your filtering of answers, for me it's above

Comment: http://chongzuo.guiju.cc/wenda/M11i5DFxmXdg.html and http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.273239544735163*pi